# Возвращение неопределенности NaN

Tags: jquery, modx, javascript

Добрый день! Пишу интернет магазин. Разбираю проблему поведения корзины. В ней значит лежат нужные товары, после того как мы накидали их в свою корзину. Рядом с каждым товаром стоят значения числа купленных товаров, цена и общая стоимость товара (в зависимости от его количества). Еще у каждого товара есть регуляторы количества товара + и -. Скрипт очень простой получается атрибут нужного поля и по нему идет расчет:

```
$('.minus').bind('click', function()
  {
    var itemNum=$(this).attr('data-extend'); // Уникальный id товара
    var c = $("#myinput"+itemNum).val(); // Количество товара
    var p = $("#myprice"+itemNum).val(); // Цена товара
    c--;
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).val(c);
    $("#mycost"+itemNum).text((c * p));
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).trigger('submit');
  });

  $(".plus").click(function()
  {
    var itemNum=$(this).attr('data-extend');
    var c = $("#myinput"+itemNum).val();
    var p = $("#myprice"+itemNum).val();
    c++;
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).val(c);
    $("#mycost"+itemNum).text(( c * p));
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).trigger('submit');
  });
```

Html-код выглядит так:

```
<form method="post" class="ms2_form form-inline" role="form">
   <p class="minus" data-extend="[[+id]]"></p>  
   <input type="text" id="myinput[[+id]]" name="count" value="[[+count]]" max-legth="4"/>
   <p class="plus" data-extend="[[+id]]"></p>
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/change"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></button>
   <input type="hidden" id="myprice[[+id]]" value="[[+price]]"/>        
   <span id="mycost[[+id]]">[[+cost]]</span> руб.
</form>
```

Не пугайтесь значений обрамленных в квадратные скобки, это от Modx идет присвоение разных значений. Суть такая же как на чистом php. Хотелось бы понять почему, когда товар стоит дешево, к примеру, рублей 350, то изменение количества товара приводит адекватному изменения общей стоимости данного товара. А если товар стоит допустим, 3500 руб, то клики по + и - (изменение количества) приводит к тому, что возвращается NaN значение в поле общей стоимости товара (mycost[[+id]]). Что я упускаю? Прошу помощи у опытных на js людей, надеюсь ответят мне, так я как я довольно ясно изложил проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было простым! Невнимательность банальная... Из поля myprice поступало число с пробелом, если оно было больше 1000, тоесть так 1 000. Удалив этот пробел, все заработало).

```
 $('.minus').bind('click', function()
  {    
    var itemNum=$(this).attr('data-extend');   
    var c = $("#myinput"+itemNum).val();
    var p = $("#myprice"+itemNum).val();
    c--;
    var priceNum = p.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).val(c);
    var all = c * priceNum; 
    $("#mycost"+itemNum).text((all));
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).trigger('submit');
  });

  $(".plus").click(function()
  {    
    var itemNum=$(this).attr('data-extend');   
    var c = $("#myinput"+itemNum).val();
    var p = $("#myprice"+itemNum).val();
    var priceNum = p.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    c++;    
    var all = c * priceNum; 
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).val(c);
    $("#mycost"+itemNum).text((all));
    $("#myinput"+itemNum).trigger('submit');
  });
```